# How does Internet Explorer Developer Tools refresh the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an unusual problem that IE F12 Dev Tools seems to be able to workaround. When my javascript is inserted into a page which contains a frameset with multiple frames, the src tag for one of the frames does not get updated and so the document it contains is not navigated and the frame contains the wrong page.

My javascript is not public domain so i can't post it here but when i fired up F12 Dev Tools to take a look and did Select Element i found that the page had somehow been refreshed and was now working. Hitting F5 or refresh on the browser does not get it working.

It seems a long shot that someone could tell me exactly how F12 refreshes the DOM. Maybe someone can tell me how i could add code (event logger?) to the page find out what is happening to it when F12 Dev Tools starts operating on it?

Comment: are you loading your code from a js file?

Comment: My code is injected into the page using functionality provided by mshtml.dll